# How to make (a piano) sound when instance is a certain location?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, audio

Currently I am creating pendulum waves in geometry nodes in Blender 3.4. Everything regarding movement works perfectly but what I want to add is a sound when each pendulum hits the ground or wall. I have been searching for a solution for a long time. I tried scripting as well but making a script in Blender is not my best skill. Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: The 3D audio system in blender hasnt been touched in years. You shouldn't be relying on it. Ideally you should just have your geometry node system output a boolean of whether or not a sound should play. Then write a simple python script to check the value every frame and create an array. You now how a list of which frames to play a piano sound.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I have been working on that by having for example the Z-location of each pendulum being outputted by the geometry nodes as an attribute. However from there I am stuck because I do not know how to incorporate this in Python and to make a script work live when you play an animation

Comment: you can get values from geometry nodes to python like in this answer from lemon: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288685/how-to-get-the-custom-attribute-of-a-bezier-point-set-by-gn

Comment: another hint: for some tasks animation nodes (free add-on) is simply the better choice doing things. E.g. procedural movement of other objects like rigs, or working with sounds in combination of movements like in your case because AN can move objects directly in its node tree which GN can't do at the moment.